# Cucumber-JVM 5 - Can you append/add a tag to the ones defined in your testRunner class?

Tags: java, maven, tags, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I have a testRunner as such:

```
@CucumberOptions( tags = {"@smoke"})
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
public class SmokeRunner_IT {

}
```

with which I want to run a subset of my features.
I also have tags on features for different environments (for example `@dev` or `@test`)

When I run my tests through maven I would like to add the environment tag to the already defined tag of `@smoke` in my testRunner. Is this possible? At the moment when I run:

```
mvn verify -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@dev"
```

it overrides my `@smoke` tag defined in the testRunner.

I found [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439284/cucumber-java-maven-is-it-possible-to-add-a-tag-to-the-ones-defined-in-the-test) about it (with a solution). But the solution was for an older version of cucumber and does not work with cucumber 5.

At the moment I am working with cucumber 5.6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short; this is not possible.

Consider instead removing the tag filter from the runner class:

```java
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
public class RunCucumberIT {

}
```

And specifying the exact set of features from the CLI.

```sh
mvn verify -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@smoke and @dev"
```

Comment: Thanks, however this significantly increases the amount of runners that I need. So have reverted back to 1.2.5 (also due to the fact that cucumber 5 does not use xstream anymore for custom datatable objects) and got it working